# glBindBufferRange and GL_MAX_UNIFORM_BLOCK_SIZE

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

In OpenGL ES you can bind a specific range of a buffer to a uniform block with `glBindBufferRange`. Is it possible to overcome the `GL_MAX_UNIFORM_BLOCK_SIZE` restriction by sending data over the limit with `glBufferData` or `glBufferSubdata`, but move the offset my shaders read from by binding a range whose size is within the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GL_MAX_UNIFORM_BLOCK_SIZE` is explicitly a restriction on the size of the *range* you use in `glBindBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ...)`. How big the entire buffer's storage is is irrelevant (save that the range must be within the storage, obviously), so there's nothing to "overcome".